# Regex to find 2 words before and after a keyword

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find 2 words before and after a keyrowrd like below:

```
Here is a testing    string with    some more testing strings.

Keyword - with
Result  - "testing string with some more"
```

Here is a regex I prepared but is not working for spaces in between.

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?\S*(?:\s\S+)?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using `\S*`, this means non-whitespace characters, so your spaces will get in the way.
I suggest the following regex: `(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*with\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)`, whichs means:

- `(\S+)`: text that doesn't include whitespace characters (a word).
- `/s*`: zero or more spaces (in between the words)

After using it, you'll get 4 groups that correspect to the 2 words before the `with` and 2 words after it.

Try the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/Mk67s2/1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s+){2}with(\s+[a-zA-Z]+){2}
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/988R9k/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
string testString = "Here is a testing    string with    some more testing strings.";
string keyword = "with";
string pattern = $@"\w+\s+\w+\s+{keyword}\s+\w+\s+\w+";
string match = Regex.Match(testString, pattern).Value;
```